# Where to put namespace declaration?

Tags: c++

I have many functions distributed in different header files. I want to use a namespace, like `impl` to wrap them up. Should I put a namespace declaration inside each file **OR** create another header file, say `my_impl.h` and includes all header files I implemented as below?

```
// my_impl.h 
namespace impl {
#include "impl_a.h" 
#include "impl_b.h" 
... 
}
```

Comment: Nothing is lost if you make the namespace declaration inside each header serparately. Then they still can be included and used individually (if a client wants this to do). Still, you can also provide a combined include file for all headers.

Comment: if you put it in an extra header then you didnt really "wrap them up", only via `my_impl.h` they are inside the namespace

Comment: The question as is provokes opinion-based answers. Please consider rephrasing to "What are the pros and cons of A and B?". That can be technically answered without carrying (too much of) an opinion.

Comment: Your linker will have a thoroughly bad day if you adopt the style you cite, unless "impl_a.h" and "impl_b.h" are header-only. You are also hoping that nothing is put in the global namespace.

Answer (score 4):

Usually you should prefer to declare namespace in each of the files.

The point is you might want to reuse a subset of those files in another context, with current approach, including "impl.h" gives correct namespace but include of any of the "impl_a..." will lead to bad namespace hence probably link errors since the implementation files probably do wrap the functions in the correct namespace.

As a side note, if you put namespace declarations in the .cc/implementations, why not put it also in corresponding header files ?

Answer (score 0):

Put declarations in a header like so. In an implementation file, put the namespace with whatever definitions you want inside it.

foo.h

```cpp
namespace foo {
    void first();
    int second();
}
```

first.cpp

```cpp
#include "foo.h"

namespace foo {
    void first() {}
}
```

second.cpp

```cpp
#include "foo.h"

namespace foo {
    int second() {
        return 92;
    }
}
```